# Nonlinear Matrix Equation Fixed Point Convergence

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-system, stationary-point

I have a method that searches for the fixed point of the equation

$$x = A(x)x$$

where x is a vector and A(x) is a square matrix. I am able to convert this into a fixed point method

$$x_{n+1} = A(x_{n})x_{n}$$

and in practice, this converges. I am looking for the general properties of the matrix A(x) that allow me to guarantee convergence and say something more rigorous. The matrix A(x) asymptotically approaches a stationary matrix A with stationary distribution x*. Are there examples of a sequence of matrices approaching a stationary matrix?

Let me know if that makes any sense.

Comment: I guess the obvious would be $A$ has eigenvalue 1. Rather boring example, but $A(x_n)= I$ satisfies the fixed point. Might need more information to say something more useful.

Comment: Do you know how to linearize the system about the fixed point? That method can give you ambiguous results sometimes, but it's often the best option to determine if the system converges *locally*.